# Redeclare loop_rate depending on boolean

Tags: ros, boost, thread, spinonce

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Given this example, in which I want to decide via `if` which loop_rate to use when spinning

```
      if(my_bool)  ros::Rate loop_rate(100); //Hz
      else ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
                
   //thread safe regular mutex spin
    mtx_spin.lock();
    ros::spinOnce();
    mtx_spin.unlock();
    loop_rate.sleep();
```

The compiler complains about rate not declared, as it is out of scope. But I need the `if` to decide which rate to get.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226600/redeclare-loop_rate-depending-on-boolean/) by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) on ROS Answers with karma: 748 on 2016-02-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had to move on out of the `if` and redeclare by  `loop_rate(double frequency)`, but with `ros::Rate` in front:

```
    ros::Rate loop_rate(rate_eff[type-1]/2+1);
    if(use_def) ros::Rate loop_rate(100);
```

---

Originally posted by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) with karma: 748 on 2016-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0